# Como mudar a URL principal no Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, framework

Preciso alterar a URL de um site em Codigniter, na raiz do site: "public_html" tem a pasta "application" do Framework e tem a pasta: "site_novo" que é onde está o site atual.

Ao abrir o domínio do site ele direciona para a pasta do site novo...ficando assim: ***www.meudomio.com.br/site_novo***

*Qual arquivo eu altero dentro da estrutura de pastas do Codeigniter para mudar essa URL de index? Pois por exemplo, caso eu queira mudar o nome da pasta (site_novo) para um outro qualquer o redirecionamento vai sempre jogar para o nome antigo...

---

Ao editar o `$config['base_url']` não surte efeito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O site continua sendo direcionado para: www.dominio.com.br/site_novo

Answer (score 1):

Na pasta application, tem outra pasta chamada config. Lá altere o valor do `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.pagina.com/que/voce_quiser';`

Comment: ainda não funcionou, no parâmetro estava definido somente o dominio principal...eu coloquei um /teste no final, no entanto continua direcionando para www.dominio/site_novo

Comment: vou anexar uma print na pergunta

Comment: Esse "/teste" que você colocou existe? Porque o codeigniter só tenta adivinhar a página principal, se não existir o arquivo. Nesse caso o teste deveria ser o nome de um controller onde tenha um método `index()`

Answer (score 0):

Da uma olhada no seu `.htaccess` veja se tem uma linha parecida com essa:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site_novo/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Se tiver troque por:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /teste/index.php?/$1 [L]
```